# Why is there a one second delay before the lights turn on with this new dimmer switch?

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I just installed a new dimmer switch (Lutron Skylark (SCL-153PH-WH)) in my dining room.  The previous switch was a single pole dimmer switch that would turn on the lights on immediately when switched on. The new switch is a one or two pole dimmer switch.  I found that there was only a red and orange wire in the box to connect to the red and black wires on the new switch.  I connected red to red and black to orange.  It has a one second delay when the light is turned on.  Now I wonder if I have mis-wired it or if I have a faulty switch.  Any ideas on why this is occurring and how to correct the lag so it is instant on?

Comment: What is the nature of that delay?  Does it turn the light on all-at-once after a delay?  Or is it turning the light up gradually over the delay time?

Comment: What model is the new dimmer?

Comment: It's a Lutron Skylark (SCL-153PH-WH).  Yes, it does turn on fully after a full second to whatever proper light level the dimmer slider is set to.  Also the dimmer works properly and responsively once it is turned on. Turning off is instant.

Comment: Sorry, could you distinguish clearly which behavior it exhibits?

Comment: There is a one full second delay after you turn the switch on before the fixture lights up.  The previous light switch I had there turned the light on instantly.  Now I am worried is the switch defective or did I wire it wrong?

Comment: Did you happen to change the bulbs at the same time? Are you using CF or regular bulbs?

Comment: I have regular bulbs in the fixture - it is a 5 light chandelier with the mini-base bulbs.  There was two light bulbs which were already burned out before I changed the switch, and after I detected the fact that the new switch was having the delay response to coming on, I changed the two burned out lights.  Unfortunately, that had no effect on the delay.

Comment: Do you notice this delay at any light levels, or only at lower light levels? Did you properly adjust the dimming range, as per the [instructions](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/0301646a.pdf)?

Comment: The dimming range seems appropriate - fully bright at the highest level, to very dim at the lowest level.  There is the same delay at any / all levels of the dimmer.  Once it comes on (after one full second) it comes on to the proper dimness per the setting of the slider.

Answer (score 2):

You are right HandyMan - I called Lutron and it turns out there is a micro processor in this model which allows it to work well with led bulbs which causes this delay.  It is not defective nor the wiring.  They said they have a newer version of a similar model called the Diva, which has no delay when turning on the light.  They said that there is a newer model of the Skylark coming out soon too which will eliminate the delay.  Thank you all for your help with this question! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) kindly mark my answer as the correct one (using the check mark) and feel free to post more questions!

Answer (score 0):

There are still some variables that need to be considered such as if it is the only switch on the circuit, the type of bulb you are using and the wattage. Some internet searches have revealed some negative reviews about this switch, *specifically* commenting on this delay:

**Negative review on [Lowes website](http://www.lowes.com/pd_438350-539-SCL-153PH-WH_0__?productId=4165017) on this product:**

> We purchased this as a replacement for the same type of dimmer. There is a very disconcerting lag from the time you turn the lights on until they actually light. I don't understand why that happens and it does not seem normal. I'll use it for now but intend to replace it. The switch is also way to expensive for what it is.

The best advise I can give you to put your mind at ease is to contact the manufacturer (**Lutron**) @ **+1.800.523.9466**  and verify that this is either a normal operation for your particular setup or confirm that the switch is indeed defective and needs replacement.

Kindly report back to any findings as this will help people in the future.

Comment: IMPE, the fancy-schmancy new LED/CFL compatible dimmers (as a class) do exhibit this annoying behavior - though I class it under annoying, not debilitating. I think it's just a function of the circuit they use for fancy-schmancy dimming .vs. the old resistor methods.

Comment: I wanted to say that it was related to a newer bulb - I've had experience where it takes a second for them to illuminate but the OP said everything is the same and for any definitive answer we need more information to draw a conclusion. 50 / 50 chance it is defective or this is the normal operation for this unit given the review.

Comment: In my case the bulbs switch instantly on a switch, and take a noticeable time to light on the dimmer (same bulbs.) So it's definitely the dimmer - in my case.